strongSwan Configuration for Windows Machine Certificates - how to get swanctl.conf?
Could you please help me to configure the strongSwan VPN server so that I could see and use the swanctl.conf file which is needed for strongSwan Configuration for Windows Machine Certificates.
It seems that I have preinstalled (or installed earlier) strongSwan on the Server:

Linux Wonderland 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64

When I type:

systemctl status strongswan

I get the
 strongswan.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since ...
 Main PID: 30094 (starter)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 3.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan.service
           ├─30094 /usr/lib/ipsec/starter --daemon charon --nofork
           └─30108 /usr/lib/ipsec/charon

But I can't see neither swanctl.conf file nor swanctl Directory.
I see the folder strongswan.d and files like strongswan.conf and ipsec.conf, but can't see the swanctl.conf.
I assume this could be somehow related to the legacy daemon and configuration backend, but can't how to fix this. Should I use the charon-systemd guide or am I missing something else?

You might want to read the note on Debian/Ubuntu packages in the strongSwan docs.

@ecdsa, yes, I read them, but not being an expert in the area, I am not sure could this be achieved by configuring or I, really need to install extra components and remove the existing ones? If I have to add install new components, am I correct that the only way to do so is to download the archives, unpack and compile like it is told in this guide? Aren't there any way to install with npm or other similar tools?

No, you don't have to compile anything. Just install/remove the right packages as written in the note.
